# How can add jest test coverage only for files ending 'spec.js'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have my code written under 'test' folder. and added the option for jest in package.json as

```
"collectCoverageFrom": ["test/*.{js}", "test/**/*.{js}"]
```

But this is applicable for all the js files under test folder. My requirement is to restrict the coverage only for files ending .spec.js, something like

`"collectCoverageFrom": ["test/*.spec.js", "test/**/*.spec.js"]`

Comment: What happens when you try it your way?

Comment: @dcodesmith I'm adding react components to existing app which is written in ampersand js, whose test cases are written in mocha. I'm planning to migrate it to jest later. Right now i decided to start writing test cases for the new files ending with .spec.js in jest, but don't want to do the coverage for other files in the same folder.

Comment: Coverage isn't for the spec files, it's for the actually files with the code, so you should be targeting those.